# Enable Disable every single control inside an asp panel with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

```
 $("#<%=txtfield.ClientID%> input").attr("disabled", true);
```

txtfield is my panel . It is disabling only text boxes but my panel has **TELERIK controls** raddropdownlist aspdropdownlist and a treeview . How can i disable all the elements inside a panel .

Comment: `$('#<%=txtfield.ClientID %>').children().attr('disabled', true);` you can use this to `disable normal control` but for `telerik control` you might need to `disable` 1 by 1...

Comment: What name should i use fro telerik radtreeview ? for eg i am using input for textboxes so what should be there for treeview ?

Comment: you might want to read this ..
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/treeview/client-side-programming/objects/radtreeview. To set disabled and enabled is different from normal jquery and javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should use the client-side API of the objects the Telerik controls create. This would usually be the `set_enabled(false);` call.

To call it, you need a reference to the control object. It is usually obtained like via the `$find()` method from MS AJAX like this `$find("<%=txtfield.ClientID%>").set_enabled(false);` where txtField is, by presumption, a Telerik control.

If you do not know their IDs (e.g., programmatically created controls in a loop related to some business logic), you can use the `control` property MS AJAX adds to the DOM object over which a control is instantiated. Here is a basic example:

```
            $("generic selector for all elements here").each(function (index, elem) {
                if (elem && elem.control && elem.control.set_enabled) {
                    elem.control.set_enabled(false);
                }
            });
```